# Yii model relations join

Tags: php, mysql, yii, datagridview

1. table Books
2. table Authors
3. table Authors_Category

In `Books` model have relation:

```
    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'authors' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Authors', array('author_id'=>'id')),
    }
```

In `Authors`:

```
    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'authors_category' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Authors_Category', array('author_cat'=>'id')),
    }
```

In `Books` `DataGridView` I can access `Authors_Category` fields

`$data->authors->authors_category->category_name`

But problem is in sorting `Authors_Category` colums

In `Books` model I have sorting rule:

```
    return new CActiveDataProvider(
        new FraudAlerts(),
        array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
            'sort'=>array(
                'attributes'=>array(
                    'category_name'=>array(
                        'asc'=>'Authors_Category.category_name',
                        'desc'=>'Authors_Category.category_name DESC',
                    ),
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

When I try sort by `Authors_Category` fiels I get error, that col category_name not exist.

What is wrong in my relations in `Books` model ?

Comment: In your model, in search method you have to define with criteria $criteria->with = array( 'authors_category');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Yatin Mistry pointed out, you have to [eager load](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#performing-relational-query) `authors_category` for this to work.

Yii allows you to load nested relations using [`with`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#with-detail) so this can be accomplished as follows:

```
$criteria->with = array(
    'authors.authors_category' => array('select' => array('category_name', 'id'))
);
```

The `select` limits the fields loaded via the query for improved performance. If you wish to load all the fields from `Authors_Category` just remove it.